# Path Planning/Rviz/nav stack

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running turtlebot on indigo (on ubuntu trusty) and wish to visually represent the robot's navigation path using a ring of LEDs.  I have not been able to find the line(s) of code that represent the robot's planned path.  Ideally I would like to reference this code to light the LEDs in a way that corresponds to the robots preferred heading.  Does anyone know where in the nav stack or rviz this code is hiding?

Thank you for any help!

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279328/path-planning/rviz/nav-stack/) by [therobot1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28127/therobot1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navstack publishes a path topic I believe, that will show the route it's currently following. If you subscribe to this topic then find the closest point on the path to the robots current location then you'll have a vector pointing in the direction of the next segments of the path.

I don't know if there's a simpler way, but this will definitely work.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0